# Rspec testing variables that are written in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, jruby

I'm trying to test some data with a library in jruby. The library accepts a method call with a byte array where it writes some stuff in.

Now I want to mock the "written stuff" inside the byte array. Is this possible and how can I do this?

example code:

```
def test_method
  # an empty byte array
  test = Java::byte[4142].new

  # writes values into the test variable. For example [1,2,3]
  result = library.process(test)

  test
end

# This should pass.
expect(test_method).to eq [1,2,3]
```

This is of course an oversimplified example.

Comment: Have you tried running your example? Did you have an error? If I was testing a method returned a particular string, I wouldn't mock the `String` object so I'm not sure why you'd do the same for a byte array. Can you not just compare the output of your method against another byte array?